# getting an error message on line 7 that an unary operator expected

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing a program in UNIX which doubles a number

```
if [ $# == l ]; then
  let "twice=$l*2

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   clear
   echo "twice Program"
   echo "-------------"
   echo "l * 2 = $twice"
   exit 0
 else
   clear
   echo "The argument must be an integer."
   exit 1
 fi

 exit 0
else
 clear
 echo "Only one argument is acceptable with twice."
 echo :Usage: twice argument"
 exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `}` should be `]` on that second if statement.

Comment: That was a typo when typing the question to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using l (small L) instead of 1

```
if [ $# ==  1 ]
then
  let "twice=$1*2"
  if [ $? == 0 ]; then
     echo "twice Program"
     clear
     echo "-------------"
     echo "$1 * 2 = $twice"
     exit 0
 else
     clear
     echo "The argument must be an integer."
     exit 1
 fi

 exit 0
 else
   clear
   echo "Only one argument is acceptable with twice."
   echo ":Usage: twice argument"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Can you except my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a double quote in line two which isn't properly closed.

```
  let "twice=$l*2
```

Should be

```
  let "twice=$1*2"
```

The shell interpreter choke later when dealing with unrelated double quotes.

Note that you are also confusing the letter `l` (ell) with the number `1` (one) at several places, which isn't going the shell to understand your script.

Comment: That was a typo when typing the question to stackoverflow

Comment: Then please correct all of the remaining ones still there.

Comment: if [ $# == l ]; then
  let "twice=$l*2"
fi
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   clear
   echo "twice Program"
   echo "-------------"
   echo "l * 2 = $twice"
   exit 0
 else
   clear
   echo "The argument must be an integer."
   exit 1
 fi

 exit 0
else
 clear
 echo "Only one argument is acceptable with twice."
 echo :Usage: twice argument"
 exit 1
fi

Comment: Now it just shows twice.sh Program                                  --------------------------------                                     *2 =